# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop manager

Tags: desktop, desktop-environment

How do I activate the desktop manager?  I'm getting the error message "desktop manager inactive" after installing, then removing Cairo.

When looking for alternative desktop pictures, I installed something called "Cairo" or maybe "Cairo Desktop".  I didn't like the way it took over the desktop so I tried to uninstall it, but this didn't work.

Eventually I ran `purge` in terminal, I don't have the details. I got rid of the nuisance program, with all the buttons at the bottom of the screen, but an icon "Cairo-Dock" remains.

Now when I try to install alternative "desktop" programs, I get the error message "desktop manager inactive" and the install fails.

Sorry if I'm using Windows terms, relatively new to Linux.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you did and worked your Ubuntu installation before?

Comment: Which packages did you specifically remove and why?

Comment: New to Ubuntu. Looking for good desktop picture-installed something called "Cairo" or maybe "Cairo Desktop".  After the install I got two new icons - Cairo and Cairo-Dock. Didn't like and tried to uninstall. Had trouble and eventually ran "purge" in terminal- Don't have details. I've still got "Cairo Dock", it didn't go away. Now get "desktop manager inactive" when I try other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bad that you don't know the details. Please check `~/.bash_history` for them. Use this command when you are in your home directory:

```
cat .bash_history | grep apt-get
```

This will get you the `apt-get` commands you used to purge.

Quick fix to your problem: try running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```